# Shell script running two Perl scripts based on input

Tags: shell

I have two Perl scripts for text processing based on two different input files. I would like to have one shell script that runs based on conditions.

If (input file) matches word `/extraction_reversed/` run `perlscript1.pl` otherwise run `perlscript2.pl`.

Shell script to compile in terminal:

```
sh run.sh inputfile > outputfile
```

Comment: Do you mean `inputfile` contains word?

Comment: yes inputfile contains word extraction_reversed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do something like:

```
if grep extraction_reversed "$1"; then
  perlscript1.pl "$1"
else
  perlscript2.pl "$1"
fi
```

`"$1"` will be replaced by the argument passed to the script (i.e. `inputfile`).

Comment: Yeah, but this requires the input file to be named `inputfile` and to reside in the current working dir. I think it should be passed as parameter (question also looks like it) and probably should be passed on to the perl scripts (which is not 100% clear in the question).

Comment: Oh, and welcome to U&L :)